# AWK print just the number of a field from an array. R

Tags: regex, r, awk

I am printing a list like this (info[i]):

```
DP=366
DP=181
DP=254
DP=463
```

And I want to get rid of the DP= and ending up with only the number to process afterwards the data in R.

with this script in awk I obtain the previous list:

```
substr($1,1,1) != "#"{
split ($8, info, ";");
num = asort(info);   
for ( i=1; i<=num; i++) {
    if (info[i] ~ "DP") {
        print info[i]
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose that a regex would help, but no idea to use in awk. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: (just modified your original codes ):

```
substr($1,1,1) != "#"{
split ($8, info, ";");
num = asort(info);   
for ( i=1; i<=num; i++) {
    if (info[i] ~ "DP") {
        sub(/DP=/,"",info[i])
        print info[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more columns in the input, you can say:

```
awk '{sub("[^0-9]*", "", $1)}1' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

In R one could just use:

```
 sub("^.+\\=", "", info)
```

No need for loop. Only reason to use awk would be if file were too large to fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F= '{print $2}' file
366
181
254
463
```